# minimizing the ul changes the li in a dramatic way

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have this table

[image]

when I minimize the browser, I got this:

[image]

Please look at the tabs and the select, they changed a lot.

This is my asp code

```
<div id="newUpContainer" style="width: 100%; float: left;">
        <div id="onlineBookingDiv" style="float: right; width: 40%;  padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <div id="tabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Today</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tomorrow</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Any Date</a></li>
                        <label style="float: right">
                            <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="mealTimeSelector" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TodayTab_Click">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Breakfast</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Lunch</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Dinner</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </label>
                    </ul>
```

and this is the css:

#### edit

this is the css

```
.ui-tabs {
    position: relative;/* position: relative prevents IE scroll bug (element with position: relative inside container with overflow: auto appear as "fixed") */
    padding: .2em;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: .2em .2em 0;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin: 1px .2em 0 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor {
    float: left;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active .ui-tabs-anchor,
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled .ui-tabs-anchor,
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-loading .ui-tabs-anchor {
    cursor: text;
}
.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active .ui-tabs-anchor {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    display: block;
    border-width: 0;
    padding: 1em 1.4em;
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: can you put some css code as well or jsfiddle will be helpful

Comment: @PravinVaichal I can't make a jsfiddle because it is an asp.net code, but I gave you the css for my tabs. there is another css , i can give you if you want

Comment: Yes please provide tabs and wrapper width related css will help a lot in debug

Comment: from the image it seems that in resized window your total tabs width is greater than resize window width hence tabs are falling down you may play with css media queries and padding of tabs for smaller resolution so that they will fit next to each other

Comment: @PravinVaichal where did you find that please? I may try to change the values.

Comment: I tried to put your provided code in jsfiddle still as it dont have images I cant able to debug further also it seems few styles are missing http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps this is one of the best article if you want to give a try to media queries

Comment: @PravinVaichal I have this website with the style online, I couldn't post the url here because the website prevents me, it is too long, do you know where can I post this website to you please?

Comment: @PravinVaichal Here it is http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/, search for `tabs` and you will see it.

Comment: hmm I guess if you inspect these tabs after resizing you will get .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor this selector in css if you decrease padding lets to padding: 0.3em; or less and margin of .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li to 1px 0 0 may resolve your issue but still as I haven't  seen your actual code it need to confirm

Comment: @PravinVaichal I will try and tell you what happens

Comment: @PravinVaichal I changed the values as you said, but really nothing has changed, if you want I can give you access to my computer to check the code your self, it is a simple code ,really

Comment: I would love to to look into that but right now I cant access your computer instead can you post staging server link which indicate issue will be helpful

Comment: @PravinVaichal what is `staging server link`? also, if you can access it later, you are more than welcome, really 5 minutes not more :)

Comment: @ Marco Staging server means development server where you test your code within dev team I guess I will be free after 3to4 hours if you can wait till the time

Comment: @PravinVaichal I will be waiting for you, please leave a message when you free, appreicate your help

Comment: @ Marco sure! I would like to help you

Comment: @ Marco I am free now.

Comment: @PravinVaichal yes me too, please

Comment: so how to start I mean communicate

Comment: @PravinVaichal do you have team viewer?

Comment: @PravinVaichal Ok will call you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inspect these tabs after resizing you will get .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor this selector in css if you decrease padding lets to padding: 0.3em; or less and margin of .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li to 1px 0 0 may resolve your issue

Also you may find this url [webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps)  helpful for responsive breakpoints

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your white-space in li is only for individual li objects, add white-space to all tabs:

```
.ui-tabs{
    position: relative;
    padding: .2em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution but still have the same problme